# forEach returning some jsx in a function how should this be done?

Tags: reactjs, foreach

Looping through an array want to populate a snippet of jsx in a function which is being called from a return. I know what I have done is wrong how do i make it right?

```
  const example = () => {
    return (
      <div className="row text-center" style={{marginTop: '100px'}}>
        <Workbook filename="example.xlsx" element={<button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Try me!</button>}>

          <Workbook.Sheet data={dataArray[0].rows} name="Sheet A">
            { 
              dataArray.forEach((item) => { return (<Workbook.Column label={item.columns.text} value={Item.columns.dataField} />) });
            }
          </Workbook.Sheet>
          <Workbook.Sheet data={data2} name="Another sheet">
            <Workbook.Column label="Double aaa" value={row => row.aaa * 2}/>
            <Workbook.Column label="Cubed ccc " value={row => Math.pow(row.ccc, 3)}/>
          </Workbook.Sheet>
        </Workbook>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't return from a [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

You should use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
  const example = () => {
    return (
      <div className="row text-center" style={{marginTop: '100px'}}>
        <Workbook filename="example.xlsx" element={<button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Try me!</button>}>

          <Workbook.Sheet data={dataArray[0].rows} name="Sheet A">
            { 
              dataArray.map(item => <Workbook.Column label={item.columns.text} value={Item.columns.dataField} />);
            }
          </Workbook.Sheet>
          <Workbook.Sheet data={data2} name="Another sheet">
            <Workbook.Column label="Double aaa" value={row => row.aaa * 2}/>
            <Workbook.Column label="Cubed ccc " value={row => Math.pow(row.ccc, 3)}/>
          </Workbook.Sheet>
        </Workbook>
      </div>
    );
  };
```